# Pandas Insert Rows and Columns for Multi Index header

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Problem:
Inserting rows and columns for a multi index header dataframe in pandas like below (refer Original dataframe)
I would like to add 3 new rows after Header 4 and 3 new columns for each of Header3

Code tried:

I have tried this before for a single level header but not sure how to do it for multiple level header

```
df["New_Column"] = ""
```

Original dataframe:

| Header1 | A |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Header2 | B |  |  |  | C |  |  |  | D |  |  | E |  |  |  |  |
| Header3 | B1 |  | B2 |  | C1 |  |  |  | D1 |  |  | E1 |  |  | E2 |  |
| Header4 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| Date | 25206 | 0 | 0 | 25206 | 0 | 0 | 25206 | 0 | 0 | 254645 | 25206 | 0 | 0 | 25206 | 0 | 0 |
| 2019-07-01 | 24903 | 0 | -291.2 | 24903 | 0 | -291.2 | 24903 | 0 | -291.2 | 209717 | 24903 | 0 | -291.2 | 24903 | 0 | -291.2 |
| 2019-08-01 | 24601 | 0 | 0 | 24601 | 0 | 0 | 24601 | 0 | 0 | 216603 | 24601 | 0 | 0 | 24601 | 0 | 0 |
| 2019-09-01 | 23794 | 0 | 0 | 23794 | 0 | 0 | 23794 | 0 | 0 | 224060 | 23794 | 0 | 0 | 23794 | 0 | 0 |
| 2019-10-01 | 17030 | 0 | 0 | 17030 | 0 | 0 | 17030 | 0 | 0 | 304037 | 17030 | 0 | 0 | 17030 | 0 | 0 |
| 2019-11-01 | 3175.8 | 0 | 0 | 3175.8 | 0 | 0 | 3175.8 | 0 | 0 | 281848 | 3175.8 | 0 | 0 | 3175.8 | 0 | 0 |
| 2019-12-01 | 40123 | 0 | 0 | 40123 | 0 | 0 | 40123 | 0 | 0 | 357329 | 40123 | 0 | 0 | 40123 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-01-01 | 22405 | 0 | 0 | 22405 | 0 | 0 | 22405 | 0 | 0 | 304961 | 22405 | 0 | 0 | 22405 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-02-01 | 6780 | 16356 | 0 | 6780 | 16356 | 0 | 6780 | 16356 | 0 | 347356 | 6780 | 16356 | 0 | 6780 | 16356 | 0 |
| 2020-03-01 | 3081.8 | 16667 | 0 | 3081.8 | 16667 | 0 | 3081.8 | 16667 | 0 | 404555 | 3081.8 | 16667 | 0 | 3081.8 | 16667 | 0 |
| 2020-04-01 | 6471.8 | 16667 | 0 | 6471.8 | 16667 | 0 | 6471.8 | 16667 | 0 | 272154 | 6471.8 | 16667 | 0 | 6471.8 | 16667 | 0 |
| 2020-05-01 | 6780 | 1993.5 | 0 | 6780 | 1993.5 | 0 | 6780 | 1993.5 | 0 | 325830 | 6780 | 1993.5 | 0 | 6780 | 1993.5 | 0 |
| 2020-06-01 | 7088.2 | 31341 | 0 | 7088.2 | 31341 | 0 | 7088.2 | 31341 | 0 | 246709 | 7088.2 | 31341 | 0 | 7088.2 | 31341 | 0 |

Desired Output:

| Header1 |  |  |  | A |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Header2 |  |  |  | B |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | C |  |  |  |
| Header3 |  |  |  | B1 |  |  |  |  | B2 |  |  |  |  | C1 |  |  |  |
| Header4 | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | 1 | 2 | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | 3 | 4 | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| New Row 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| New Row 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| New Row 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Date |  |  |  | 25205.62 | 0 |  |  |  | 0 | 25205.62 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 25205.62 | 0 |
| ###### |  |  |  | 24903.16 | 0 |  |  |  | -291.2 | 24903.16 |  |  |  | 0 | -291.2 | 24903.16 | 0 |
| ###### |  |  |  | 24600.7 | 0 |  |  |  | 0 | 24600.7 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 24600.7 | 0 |
| ###### |  |  |  | 23794.16 | 0 |  |  |  | 0 | 23794.16 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 23794.16 | 0 |
| ###### |  |  |  | 17029.62 | 0 |  |  |  | 0 | 17029.62 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 17029.62 | 0 |
| ###### |  |  |  | 3175.77 | 0 |  |  |  | 0 | 3175.77 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 3175.77 | 0 |
| ###### |  |  |  | 40122.91 | 0 |  |  |  | 0 | 40122.91 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 40122.91 | 0 |
| ###### |  |  |  | 22405.49 | 0 |  |  |  | 0 | 22405.49 |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 22405.49 | 0 |
| ###### |  |  |  | 6780 | 16356.39 |  |  |  | 0 | 6780 |  |  |  | 16356.39 | 0 | 6780 | 16356.39 |
| ###### |  |  |  | 3081.81 | 16667.17 |  |  |  | 0 | 3081.81 |  |  |  | 16667.17 | 0 | 3081.81 | 16667.17 |
| ###### |  |  |  | 6471.82 | 16667.17 |  |  |  | 0 | 6471.82 |  |  |  | 16667.17 | 0 | 6471.82 | 16667.17 |
| ###### |  |  |  | 6780 | 1993.54 |  |  |  | 0 | 6780 |  |  |  | 1993.54 | 0 | 6780 | 1993.54 |
| ###### |  |  |  | 7088.16 | 31340.8 |  |  |  | 0 | 7088.16 |  |  |  | 31340.8 | 0 | 7088.16 | 31340.8 |

Comment: Please include more details, and a text sample of your actual dataframe.

Comment: Thankyou. I have dont that now.

Comment: Thank you. Will you please also provide a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: @user17242583 - I have added a sample output dataframe...Hope that helps

Comment: One more thing. Will you please send the result of `print(df.index)` and `print(df.columns)`?

Comment: @user17242583 - I have added it now. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much, however, will you please paste those as _text_? Since they're just screenshots, I can't copy and paste them.

Comment: @user17242583 Done